# August GD Design Contest extended!

Tags: discussion

Well we keep talking about having a design contest possibly monthly so lets have one already!  So here are the requirements, specs and rules:

**Duration**: This has been extended to **the end of September**.

**Winner**: Winner is determined by the amount of up votes given by the community.  If on the **1st of October** there is a tie a new, extended, question will be created and GD members will be allowed to vote for 5 days until Friday, September 6th the winner will be determined. If its still a tie mods will decide the winner.

**Prize**: Pride and ego all good?

**Participation**: This is open to everyone who can post and I know myself and others gladly encourage it.  Everyone here should be professional and no plagiarism will be allowed or tolerated.  If an entry is found to be plagiarized I myself feel that member should be deleted from the contest and personally not allowed to participate in any GD contests here on.

**Criticism**: We all have our own style, passion, and way we design so please be considerate and just to be safe I ask when viewing please be supportive and positive to the members that are posting.

**Entry**:  Please only have **one** entry per **each contest**.  After posting please leave it up and do not remove or change it even if you feel you are not going to win.  All entries may be allowed up to the last day, September 1st, till the winner is decided than this will be closed.

**Terms**: Please remember this is a public board and any entry may be used in any advertisements by Stack and its affiliates if they so desired.

---

**Challenge!!!**
I know we have talked about doing a logo contest but not everyone here likes doing logos so I felt maybe if we did something different it would help break the ice.  That said this contest will be about color.  You may post anything you want to design as long as the 3 out of 5 colors below are included in the piece.  That means if you love illustration, branding, logo, typography, etc. etc. it is welcome in this contest.

Good Luck!!!

If you have any questions please post them in the comment below.

[image]

- **RGB**: 78/84/45; 244/90/4; 92/18/2; 164/41/10; 180/90/0
- **Hex**: 4A582D; F45A04; 5C1202; A4290A; B45A00

Comment: Re the Terms: Entries may be re-used, but attribution is required. (That is probably a good thing as it gets the designer's name associated with a good design)

Comment: Could you add the colour specifications to the Challenge, please? The image is illegible.

Comment: @AndrewLeach - right-click and view image...it's just scaled down.

Comment: I'm on an iPad. That's not easy to do.

Comment: @AndrewLeach tap! http://i.stack.imgur.com/2Octc.png

Comment: Still not very legible. Anyway, here they are: RGB 78/84/45, 244/90/4, 92/18/2, 164/41/10, 180/90/0; Hex 4A582D, F45A04, 5C1202, A4290A, B45A00.

Comment: Me likey :) just out of interest, was that a randomized palette or did you choose it, and why those colours?

Comment: It was random but I liked the colors because the closely resemble a fall that is around our corner.

Comment: Black and white also allowed or strictly that palette?

Comment: Any other colors are allowed.  Only requirement is that 3 of them must be used implemented in the design.

Comment: Just mentioning that [the Photo.SE site's photography contests](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2657/weekly-featured-image-ongoing-contest/) have strict rules for "no downvotes" and "no criticism, friendly suggestions only" - presumably because criticism in cold text from strangers online always sounds harsher than intended: presumably they found it got nasty. I don't know if we should have similar rules, but we should def remember that it ALWAYS sounds much harsher than intended. So maybe phrase like "I think you could improve X, by..." not "X sucks because..."?

Comment: @user568458 I completely agree. To "be supportive and positive", as Matt mentioned, sounds great to me.

Comment: Are we posting our creations here or...?

Comment: @Ryan Yes! Post it as an answer

Comment: perhaps a quarterly contest? I honestly intended to do something.. but the last week around here has been a madhouse so... no time.

Comment: quarterly is an awful long time how about every 2 months?  do we need to extend this?

Comment: Just saying a ~week wasn't enough.

Comment: Did anyone post an entry?